# show the number of characters of the maxLength rule in the template using formBuilder

Tags: angular

I'm trying to validate that my text field has a maximum length of 'x' value. and I want this message to appear dynamically from the view.

```
this.register= this.formBuilder.group({
 cellphone:[
  null,
  Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])
]
})
```

for example:

```
<div *ngIf="this.register.get("cellphone").hasError('maxlength')">
(maxlength is: {{}} digits);
</div>
```

How can I do it?
I need to know the value of the rule. If I define that the text field has a maxlength of 5, I would like to get this 5 dynamically in the view. 5 may vary, so I want to do it dynamically

Comment: Have you tried implementing it? What is the problem you have found? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @bracco23 Yes friend, of course I have tried, but I do not know how to get the value for maxlength that I have implemented in the rule. I'm just missing this.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/forms/reactive-forms/reactive-forms_validation.html): For example, to create a loginForm with a validation on username field with a variable `minlength`

**Component**

```
minlength = 5;
username = new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.minlength)]);

loginForm: FormGroup = this.builder.group({
    username : this.username 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()">
    <input  type="text" name="username" id="username" [formControl]="username">

<div [hidden]="username.valid || username.untouched">
  <div>
    The following problems have been found with the username:
  </div>

  <div [hidden]="!username.hasError('minlength')">
    Username can not be shorter than {{ minlength }} characters.
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="!username.hasError('required')">
    Username is required.
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

You can inspire it to create your cellphone form.

Comment: thank you, I am at this point. but I need to know the value of the rule. If I define that the text field has a maxlength of 5, I would like to get this 5 dynamically in the view. 5 may vary, so I want to do it dynamically

Comment: You are too kind and intelligent, thank you very much for your effort. but I do not know if it makes me understand, but I mean to obtain the value directly from the rule that I have defined? I do not want to always define a variable every time I want to get that value

Comment: Thanks for your compliment. But as my knowledge, there isn't noway to read the validator. That means we can't get the value ``minlength``. There is a ticket opened in angular for that point. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461

Comment: You can see, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you has some like

```
    this.myform3=this.fb.group({
      item:['',Validators.maxLength(10)]
    })

<div *ngIf="myform3"  [formGroup]="myform3">
  <input formControlName="item">
  <div *ngIf="myform3.get('item').errors?.maxlength">
     <pre>{{myform3.get('item').errors|json}}</pre>
  </div> 
</div>
```

You can see that in myform3.get('item').errors?.maxlength.requiredLength has the required length and in myform3.get('item').errors?.maxlength.actualLength the actual length so you can write

```
  <div *ngIf="myform3.get('item').errors?.maxlength">
    the max length is {{myform3.get('item').errors?.maxlength.requiredLength}} 
    and you write {{myform3.get('item').errors?.maxlength.actualLength}} characteres
 </div>
```

Tip:all validators return an object if is not valid. You can check the return object as you see in the example. As consequencie, if we write our own custom validators, we would make that it return a representative object